# Relating Two Tables Through One Related Table In Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I seem to have a hard time understanding how to properly query as the logic of it gets confused as I try to use different operators.

Anyways, I have three tables: Customer, Cpe, Equipment. I want data from equipment but in order to do that, I must use Customer to relate to Cpe, then relate that table to Equipment.

The relationships are as follows:

Customer has many Cpe customerid > customerid
Cpe has one Equipment equipid > equipid

There is nothing relating Customer and Equipment except the Cpe table.

I specifically want to select the Customer.customerid, Customer.name, Equipment.nickname, Customer.customerstatus, Customer.installationdate. But I also want to only select the customers who have Equipment.nickname LIKE %SIM%. So what I have is:

```
$baicell_customers = Customer::with('Cpe')
->with('Cpe.Equipment')
->select('Customer.customerid', 'Customer.name', 
'Equipment.nickname', 'Customer.customerstatus', 
'Customer.installationdate' => function($query){
$query->where('Equipment.nickname', 'LIKE', '%SIM%');
})
->orderBy('Customer.name', 'asc');
->get();
```

But this gets me nothing. I'm not great at the whole relating one table to another and to throw in the fact that I have to use a related table to get info from another is just bonkers for me so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this: [Has many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). There is an article that can help you, check the [tutorial](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-has-many-through-eloquent-relationship-tutorialexample.html).

Comment: @HCK I was actually looking hasManyThrough just a moment ago and I can't seem to get that to work but it sort of seems like it might if I were to do it correctly. I might be wrong but it seems it's meant for a A Many > B Many > C relationship chain though.

Comment: @HCK So I've been looking at this for most of the night as well as since 8 AM this morning and can't seem to get this to work correctly. I've set Customer to have a function named equipment() that does:

    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Here\Equipment', 'App\Models\Here\Cpe', 'customerid', 'equipid', 'customerid', 'cpeid');

So it's the Equipment model, then the Cpe model, then the relation of customer to cpe, then the relation of cpe to equipment, then the local key of customer and cpe.

Comment: Actually, there is a new type of relationship that suits your case, it will be available in the 5.8 version: HasOneThrough, you can check the commit code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26057/files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I gave up on doing this in the Eloquent style for the time being. It took some time but I was able to get a DB::connection('table') query to work. Here's the code:

```
$baicell_customers = DB::connection('azotel')->select("SELECT distinct customers.name, customers.customerid as id, customers.installationdate, customers.customerstatus[1] as status, equipment.nickname as ap FROM  cpe INNER JOIN customers on customers.customerid = cpe.customerid INNER JOIN equipment on equipment.equipid = cpe.equipid WHERE equipment.nickname LIKE '%SIM%' order by name ASC");
```

This worked perfectly as intended and yet I can't get it work correctly in Eloquent at this point but that's alright for now. If this helps anyone figure out what the Eloquent version would be, I would still love to hear it. Otherwise, this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a many to many, you will be able to get it with the following. In general in Laravel you get out the models and do something with the data, do not do it with selects unless you are in a highly enterprise oriented system. Your naming conventions is off also since cpe is a pivot table basically see [Laravel Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

```
public class Customer
{
    public equipments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipment', 'INSERT CPE TABLE NAME', 'customerid', 'equipid ');
    }
}

$customer = Customer::with('equipments')->all()->first();


foreach($customer->equipments as $equipment)
{
    $equipment->nickname;
}
```

Even thou you say cpe only can have one equipment the design is a many to many, to circumvent this you can do.

```
$equipment = $customer->equipments->first();
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work and the tables are quite large as this is multiple databases for a business. And I want to only have customers that have equipment with a nickname that has 'SIM' in it.

Comment: Then you can use where has method to get it. But if you can't even get this initially to work you are on deep waters. This should work, what is the error?